# Is there a way to revert indexes to a previous version?

Tags: sql, solr, lucene

I'm working with Solr Lucene. I had some issues with connection to the SQL server and I was trying to play around with the DataImport to check various scenarios.

And finally I ended up with cleaning up all the indexes in the database, and now I'm still facing issue with connecting to the SQL Server database. Is there anything which I can do to revert the indexes to a previous version?

This is what I can find at the moment

```
Last Modified:18 days ago
Num Docs:0
Max Doc:0
Deleted Docs:0
Version:9093
Segment Count:0
Optimized:
Current:
```

I just to know whether I can load the database from some previous version like Version 9000 or something?

Comment: Do you have any backups?

Comment: Not AFAIK. While I personally have great affection for Solr, stability of its indexes was always an issue. Recovering a previous one would be completely out of the question; you'll have to rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: I don't think we have a back up any where. But right now when I do a full import I'm getting Java OutOFMemory error and Java Heap space is consistently at 100%. I'm running out of ideas on how to clean up the same.

Comment: null:java.lang.IllegalStateException: this writer hit an OutOfMemoryError; cannot flush

java.lang.IllegalStateException: this writer hit an OutOfMemoryError; cannot complete forceMerge

null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't revert your indexes. You have to do a full data import. You should do delta-import for changes in your SQL database and play around with a few cores to simply your import queries if possible.

Comment: I did try to do a full import but as I mentioned earlier there is something wrong with the SQL server which we are connecting to. Moreover the DB to be imported is very huge and when I try that I'm getting Java Heap Space error. And now the Java Heap space is @ 100% and I'm not getting any clue how to clean up the same.

Comment: Have you tried sharding? Maybe rethink the architecture of how you might want to utilize the index?

Comment: Ok probably I'll need to have an incremental indexing approach. But yet not sure how to clean the heap space.